# OpenXML SDK: Is there a command to "refresh" the spreadsheet that was created?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I write applications that create PDF files and Excel files. While generating PDF files, I noticed that some of the features that were inserted in the file, did not show up visually. I was informed of a statement that "refreshes" the file and now all the features are visible.

I am having the exact same problem with Excel generation. I need one of my columns to self-adjust to the width of the widest entry (in the same fashion as double-click interactively). I was told about this solution:

`"In OpenXML you can set the spreadsheet column properties so that it will be auto-sized when the spreadsheet is opened in Excel. Set BestFit=true and CustomWidth=true when creating the column."`

[How to implement the feature that adjusts an Excel column to the precise width, programmatically??](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b1d38e45-35a9-4072-ad43-9395533dab57/how-to-implement-the-feature-that-adjusts-an-excel-column-to-the-precise-width-programmatically?forum=oxmlsdk)

I added this statement to my source code:

```
 Column column2 = new Column() { Min = (UInt32Value)2U, Max = (UInt32Value)2U, Width=7, BestFit = true, CustomWidth = true };
```

But the column is too narrow. I tried without the `Width=7` but in that case the width is assumed to be zero an the column disappears altogether.

TIA

Comment: if you know font family and size of a string you can use GDI+ method "MeasureString()" to get width and height. Then you can apply it to column width or row height.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no. Setting the BestFit and CustomWidth properties aren't enough. You still have to manually calculate the column width.

It's best to use a third-party library for this. Suggestions are [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) and [SpreadsheetLight](http://spreadsheetlight.com/). All of these free open source libraries provide the auto-fit feature. Disclosure: I wrote SpreadsheetLight.